# How to get JWTToken from ASPNET Core Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to make a request to a protected API, so I need to add a authorization request header to HttpClient like this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
```

But how to get the Authentication Token ("Your Oauth token") from a controller?

PS: I am already authenticated to Identity Server 4.
Application developed in AspNetCore.

Full code:

```
    [Authorize] //Already authenticated
    public IActionResult SomeControllerAction()
    {
        var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity; //where is JWTToken??
        var JWTTokne = "how to get?";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", JWTTokne);
            var result = client.PostAsync("someurl", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
            //more code to handle result....
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: is that controller action an [Authorized] one? IOW is the controller invoked using a client that has sent the Authorization header in the request?

Comment: Yes, it is Authorized an already authenticated action.

Answer (score 19):

Core:

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

Or this:

```
var token = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
```

For access_token in MVC 5 controller I used:

```
var token = (User as ClaimsPrincipal).FindFirst("access_token").Value
```

In the protected web api 2 (not core) method I used:

```
var access_token = ControllerContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
```

Comment: Request.Headers["Authorization"] will most certainly not work for me, it just returns null. The first method works however I'm really obsessed with finding out why the other one won't work. Do you have any guesses? (I use Oidc, everything works fine, I just want to explicitly reach the Auth header)

Comment: .Net Core 3.1 I get the bearer token with this. Hope it helps.                        HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var tokenHeaders);

Comment: In ConfigureServices I have
builder.AddIdentityServerAuthentication("Bearer", (JwtBearerOptions options) =>
{options.Authority = "blabla";
options.Audience = "api1";
}, (options) =>
{
options.TokenRetriever = new Func<HttpRequest, string>(req =>
{
var fromHeader = TokenRetrieval.FromAuthorizationHeader();
var fromQuery = TokenRetrieval.FromQueryString();
var token = fromHeader(req) ?? fromQuery(req);
return token;});
                });

I dont know it has an affect or not. Regards.

Answer (score 5):

you can get the access token by using:

```
// Get the access token.
var accessToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

var client = new HttpClient();

// Set the access token as the bearer token (Authorization header of the request).

client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
```

Comment: What does the GetTokenAsync method do under the hood? Why not use Request.Headers["Authorization"]?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the HTTP Context since you're in a controller you can  just get the token from the Header at `HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]`. This obviously only works if the client has put that header in the request.

Comment: Well, not in my case. The authentication system works as expected but I cannot explicitly get the auth token.

Comment: This works for me when  I set the Authorization header in postman with the value "Bearer token"

Answer (score 0):

With AspNet Core 2.0 and the new authentication system, you simply use the extension methods ontop of HttpContext.

```
HttpContext context;
await context.GetTokenAsync("access_token")
```

and in a MVC controller

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Get(){
         var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

    }

}
```