# Blazor Server MSAL View & Controller Role Based Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server Web App that uses Azure AD via OIDC to authorize access within the Razor Components. This is working fine, I can access the User ClaimsPrincipal throughout my Razor Components after signing in. The problem is, all of the business logic for the application lies in controllers (in the same project) that are called from the Razor Components via HTTP. I can't figure out how to get a JWT tokenized version of the user claims to pass in the Authorization header to call my controller.

Here's some of my code.

`DevicesController.cs`:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator", "User")]
    public class DevicesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<DevicesController> _logger;
        private readonly AppSettings _config;
        private readonly IDeviceEnvironmentService _deviceEnvironmentService;

        public DevicesController(ILogger<DevicesController> logger, IOptions<AppSettings> config, IDeviceEnvironmentService deviceEnvironmentService,)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _config = config.Value;
            _deviceEnvironmentService = deviceEnvironmentService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<object>> Index()
        {
            try
            {
                return await _deviceEnvironmentService.GetEnvironmentDevices(_config.Environment);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, $"Failed to fetch devices. Exception details: {ex}");
                return StatusCode(500, "Failed to fetch devices.");
            }
        }
}
```

`DeviceIndex.razor`:

```
@code {
    [CascadingParameter] Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    private ClaimsPrincipal User { get; set; }
    private List<DeviceEnvironment> devices { get; set; }
    private HubConnection hubConnection;  

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateTask;
        User = authState.User;

        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/DeviceHub"))
        .Build();

        hubConnection.On("ReceiveMessage", () =>
        {
            LoadData();
            StateHasChanged();
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
        LoadData();
    }

    public bool IsConnected => hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;

    protected async void LoadData()
    {
        devices = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<DeviceEnvironment>>($"{NavigationManager.BaseUri}api/devices");
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.Run();
```

Is there a way I get a JWT token within my Razor Components I can pass via the Authorization header to my controllers? Or is there a way that I can access the User Claims via the HttpContext without passing a token to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

As you already has the method to get the user claims from

```
private ClaimsPrincipal User { get; set; }
```

Please check if below is the way you may want to get access token from the obtained claims principal

```
var token = (User as ClaimsPrincipal).FindFirst("access_token").Value
```

You can get the authorization  token from the Header like below  which works only if the client sends the header in the request.

```
HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]
```

**References:**

1. Also please check this [Implement app roles authorization with Azure
   AD and ASP.NET Core | Software Engineering (damienbod.com)](https://damienbod.com/2021/02/01/implement-app-roles-authorization-with-azure-ad-and-asp-net-core/)
2. [c# - How to get JWTToken from ASPNET Core Controller? - Stack
   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617530/how-to-get-jwttoken-from-aspnet-core-controller)

Comment: "access_token" is null when I try this